# Kill Spring Cloud Client if Server is not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

Is there a simple way to kill a Spring Cloud Config Client on startup if the server is not running? I haven't been able to find any examples online, and I'm wondering if there is some code that already exists that can be reused, or if this is something that is better handled on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue #1 is now closed.  You can use `spring.cloud.config.failFast=true`.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.  You can create an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues) if you'd like.

Comment: Actually, that was [issue number 1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1)